# Migration from Mysql to Oracle ORA-04098 SYSTEM.MD_PROJECTS_TRG error

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

Pls, could you help me on the following issues:

I would like to migrate from mysql to oracle. I used Oracle Sql developer. I import Mysql thirty packet but when i was start migration i get this error

ORA-04 098: trigger 'SYSTEM.MD_PROJECTS_TRG' is invalid and failed re-validation

then migration stop

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever seen this post and tried this solutions?
A problem of constraint or foreign key surely?

Just so you know the Data Move operation actually performs 3 different actions in the following order:

```
1. Disable all constraints (FKs,PKs). 
2. Move data using multiple streams so that it can migrate more than 1 table at any time. 
3. Enable all constraints (FKs,PKs)
```

It appears that for some reason SQL Developer is failing on step 1 where it is trying to disable the constraints. Have you tried to generate the data move scripts for an off-line data migration?. You can look at the disable constraint scripts and run them manually before attempting the on-line data migration again. Hope that works.

1. Yes you can specify a different schema (need to use the connection for it). But you will have to use the same repository that you used for migration so that it can pick up the mappings for the source database.
2. For the Data move issues, you can try the followiing:
   a. For moving the failed tables one by one i.e. right click on the table in the source database and choose '**copy to oracle**' and then choose only data migration (append mode). 
   b. You can also try changing the default DATE formats for the source database in the SQL Developer to the actual one used in the source database. The default it uses is mm/dd/yyyy which may not be the right one in your environment( --> **Preferences**-->**Migration**-->**Data Move** options). Some times this also causes problems when migrating data

From my personal experience, SQL Developer creates a log file in an XML format under \localuser\applications... directory. So you will have to dig a bit more to find out the log file which will contain the actual error.

More informations in this link -> https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2357687&tstart=90

Comment: I have one table and it doesn't have constraints. I try migration but same error but i click copy to oracle it was work. 

Do i migrate this way?

Comment: Yes try exactly like this! This allowed several people to solve the problem of migration.